# CRL not working over http proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, certificate

This is my situation.

```
client -> http proxy -> remote web server
```

LDAP ports and HTTP ports are blocked on firewall at client.

When sending request client must check CRL of remote web server's certificate to verify it's origin.

We did set `ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;` to do that and it works fine in a setup without a proxy. With proxy, we get the following error:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
>   channel.

Servers CRL file is accessible via IE in same setup.

I have looked around, but found nothing.

Comment: Is this related to WPF?

Comment: It is related to WPF and WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, I found the answer through experimentation.

If you want your CRL to work via proxy:

1. you might want to setup proxy for connections your application does (we had that already, so it was not really a problem).
2. you need to set `netsh winhttp` proxy, to point to your proxy (use `set proxy myproxy:proxyport` in netsh winhttp console)

Comment: Hi, could you post the example code here? I think I'm meeting the same issue, our C# http client is behind a proxy to call  restful API (HTTPS), and it failed to check CRL, we need to enable the httpclient to call API and check CRL with the same proxy at application level as we don't want to set proxy in the system level.